# How to Upload an Excel File in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, js-xlsx

so I have this app where I upload a csv file using FileUploader. However now my requirement is to also allow excel files. The problem is that FileUploader doesn't support excel as it reads garbage. This is my attempt at parsing an excel file based on this example http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/

Code:

```
        var fileUpload = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
        var domRef = fileUpload.getFocusDomRef();
        var file = domRef.files[0];
        var XLSX = new ExcelPlus();
        XLSX.createFile(["CT_MAIN"]);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var strCSV = e.target.result;
            var arr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new 
            Uint8Array(strCSV));

          //  var arr = fixData(strCSV);

            console.log('data');
            console.log(arr);

            var workbook = XLSX.read(arr, {type : 'base64'});
             console.log('output');
             console.log(workbook);

            //var output = toCsv(workbook); 
            //each one of the rows in the csv file
            //var rows = arr;//strCSV.split("\n");
            var rows = arr.split("\n");
            ..... 

        };

        //reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          //reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

If I upload a csv file using this code everything works fine. If I use an excel file I get the following

[1][Content_Types].xml ¢ [1]( [1]¬”ËNÃ0E÷HüCä-JÜ²@5í‚Ç *Q>ÀÄ“Æªc[žiiÿž‰ûB¡ j7± ÏÜ{2ñÍh²nm¶‚ˆÆ»R‹ÈÀU^7/ÅÇì%¿’rZYï  @1__f›˜q·ÃR4DáAJ¬h >€ãÚÇV ßÆ¹ 
ªZ¨9ÈÛÁàNVÞ 8Ê©ÓãÑ Ôji){^óã-I‹"{Üv^¥P!XS)bR¹rú—K¾s(¸3Õ`c[1]Þ0†½
ÝÎß»¾7 M4²©ŠôªZÆk+¿|\|z¿(Ž‹ôPúº6 h_-[ž@!‚ÒØPk‹´¬2nÏ}Ä? £LËðÂ Ýû%á  ÄßdºždN"m,à¥ÇžDO97*‚~§ÈÉ¸8ÀOíc |n¦Ñä Eøÿ ö éºóÀBÉÀ!$}‡íàÈé;{ìÐå[ƒîñ–é2þÿÿ

what am I doing wrong, or what am I missing here?

Edit: after doing var workbook = XLSX.read(arr, {type : 'base64'}); I get null for both file types. The above garbage log comes from console.log(arr);

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the file from the domRef you wouldn't need ExcelPlus. You just need to read the file as a binary string using xlsx. You will have to include the xlsx.full.min.js in your script.

```
var fileUpload = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
    var domRef = fileUpload.getFocusDomRef();
    var file = domRef.files[0];
    //var XLSX = new ExcelPlus();
    //XLSX.createFile(["CT_MAIN"]);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var name = file.name;

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

        var result = {};
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
            var rObjArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            if (rObjArr.length > 0) {
                result[sheetName] = rObjArr;
            }
        });
        var output = JSON.stringify(result, 2, 2);

        console.log('output');
        console.log(output);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured out before your comment and I used the following
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
then in the onload function
var arr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(strCSV));
The rest of the code looks the same as yours with the difference that instead of 'binary' I used 'base64'.